# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelectorAll') at line 189

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

That points to this line:

```
wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
```

Clicking the exit button causes the error.

Clicking on the exit button is supposed to remove the player, after the blue play button is clicked.

To test jsitor code click run not update.

code https://jsitor.com/KZMNnkSf5

https://jsfiddle.net/e631o2rq/

How is that fixed in the code?

```
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    let container = el.closest(".container");
    let wrappers;
    if (container) { //if multiple players
      wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".remove .wrap");
    } else { //if single player
      container = el.closest(".remove");
      wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    }
    wrappers.forEach(function (wrapper) {
      if (wrapper.player) {
        removePlayer(wrapper);
      }
    });
  }
```

It used to look like this:

```
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");
    if (wrapper.player) {
      return removePlayer(wrapper);
    }
  }



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="button-container">
<button class="exit" type="button"></button>
<button class="exit exitpPage2" type="button"></button>
<button class="exit exitpPage3" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: It’s pretty clear from the error message that `el.closest(".remove")` is `null`.

Comment: How do I fix that in the code?

Comment: Currently your code *assumes* that the element is located somewhere "underneath" an element with class "remove". That is not always the case, apparently, so you'll either have to fix your HTML or else ensure that the code posted checks to see if that `.closest()` call returns `null`.

Comment: If it's above it, how would that be fixed in the code? What would be changed in the javascript to handle that? What would  get changed in the javascript so it can look up instead of down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but it does look a little complicated. I might suggest just keeping things a lot simpler.

Here's an idea: https://jsitor.com/JOlxKAhhbL

Code attached below also so it can be read, but due to the sandboxing of iframes in stackoverflow, it fails to load the youtube player, instead, load the jsitor link above.

```js
// Note: move data-id to `.wrap` element

const DEFAULT_PLAY_OPTIONS = {
  events: {
    onReady: function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo()
    },
    onStateChange: function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      // whatever you'd like
    }
  },
  height: 360,
  host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
  playerVars: {
    autoplay: 1,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  },
  width: 640
}
const removeAllPlayers = () => {
  for (const wrapperEle of [...document.querySelectorAll('.embed-youtube.active')]) {
    wrapperEle.querySelector('iframe').remove()
    const videoEle = document.createElement('div')
    videoEle.classList.add('video', 'embed-youtube')
    wrapperEle.append(videoEle)
    const curtainEle = wrapperEle.closest('.curtain,.curtain1')
    curtainEle.classList.remove('slide')
    wrapperEle.classList.remove('active')
  }
}
const createAndPlayVideo = (playBtnEle) => {
  const curtainEle = playBtnEle.closest('.curtain,.curtain1')
  const wrapperEle = playBtnEle.closest('.wrap')
  const embedYoutubeEle = wrapperEle.querySelector('.video')
  const playOptions = {...DEFAULT_PLAY_OPTIONS}
  playOptions.videoId = wrapperEle.getAttribute('data-id')
  const player = new YT.Player(embedYoutubeEle, playOptions)
  curtainEle.classList.add('slide')
  wrapperEle.classList.add('active')
}
const bindPlayers = () => {
  for (const playBtn of [...document.querySelectorAll('.playa')]) {
    playBtn.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
      createAndPlayVideo(clickEvent.target)
    })
  }
  for (const stopBtn of [...document.querySelectorAll('.exit')]) {
    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
      removeAllPlayers()
    })
  }
}
const init = () => {
  bindPlayers()
}

init()
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #302b63;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 290px;
  gap: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.container2 .container {
  background: teal;
}

.container3 .container {
  background: green;
}

.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 255px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain1 {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain {
  margin: auto auto 40px;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}

.embed-youtube iframe,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play::before {
  position: absolute;
}

.embed-youtube iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid blue;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
  z-index: 1;
}

.embed-youtube-play::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}

.embed-youtube-play:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.embed-youtube-play:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.embed-youtube.active .embed-youtube-play {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  99.9% {
    border-color: red transparent red transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-color: blue;
  }
}

@keyframes triangle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    border-left-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exit.exitpPage2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 200px;
  left: 0;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.exit.exitpPage2::before,
.exit.exitpPage2::after {
  background-color: blue;
}

.exit.exitpPage3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  border: 5px solid purple;
}

.exit.exitpPage3::before,
.exit.exitpPage3::after {
  background-color: purple;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="curtain1 remove">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="video-one"></div>
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        <div class="video embed-youtube ">
        </div>
        <button class="playa cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container2 hide">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-two"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playb cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-three"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playc cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-four"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playd cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-five"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playe cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-six"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playf cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container3 hide">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-seven"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playg cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-eight"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playh cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-nine"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playi cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-ten"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playj cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain remove">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video-eleven"></div>
        <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
          <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
          </div>
          <button class="playk cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
  <button class="exit" type="button"></button>
  <button class="exit exitpPage2" type="button"></button>
  <button class="exit exitpPage3" type="button"></button>
</div>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

Comment: This code is set up similarly, with the container at the bottom. Would you be able to get this one to work? 

This code I am trying to get working has the play buttons at the bottom inside their own container.

https://jsitor.com/MIYiywN4HC / https://jsfiddle.net/kxhyLdr8/

What is weird about this code is that after clicking on the buttons, no errors are appearing, when there should be.

Here is a demo code of it working with the play buttons not inside their own container.

https://jsfiddle.net/24xf0avp/

Comment: No one has been able to figure out how that would be done, getting the play buttons to work inside their own container.

Comment: I'm honestly struggling to understand what you want. I think you're trying to articulate a lot of different problems or trying to achieve something that is probably beyond your current skill level. In order for everyone to help (and we will), please try and make it crystal clear of EXACTLY what you are trying to achieve. Try using a wireframe tool such as https://wireframe.cc/ to give us a view of what you want to achieve. You have a lot of javascript code and html markup, but it is very confusing, even for some of us with experience. Thanks

Comment: Here is a working demo code with only 1 button.

https://jsitor.com/Qer_1Oi9Jv / https://jsfiddle.net/1bmrwuzn/

Here is the broken code with only 1 button.

https://jsitor.com/D38vgjs3g / https://jsfiddle.net/gt57k29h/

Comment: It could be I just need to extend the javascript code so that it reaches the inner html node.

If so, how would that be done?

This was brought to my attention:

"on the button click event it probably captures the parent element instead of the target element?"

Comment: Again, please let me be clear. Can you tell what you do want 'here is a working demo' is interpreted as 'I've solved my problem'. But I don't know exactly what you want. Can you draw a wireframe or diagram that clearly shows the expected outcome please.

Comment: The only difference between the working and non working example is just the extra layer of HTML.

Nothing was touched in any other part of the code.

Comment: I was told by my instructor, the play buttons need to be inside their own container. Does this help? I am trying to get the code working where the buttons are inside their own container. The code that is broken, I am try to fix, so it works.

Comment: This is the play button inside it's own container: <div class="playButtonContainer">
  <button class="playa cover" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>

Comment: Please draw what you want. eg, what do you define as a 'container'. No more words please, just some diagrams showing the desired outcome all of the elements drawn in (big play button, your 3 exit buttons, black frame around the video, video itself, the green background, all of it). Draw separate diagrams to show what should be seen at each stage, and what happens to trigger that stage (eg, each click). Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249657/discussion-between-marci-kardon-and-dangarfield).

Comment: Hello, can you come back into chat please? I got the code working. But I had some questions to ask you about what I did.